# curl --fail without suppressing stdout

Tags: bash, http, curl, webdav

I have a script that uploads a file to a WebDav server using `curl`.

```
curl --anyauth --user user:password file http://webdav-server/destination/
```

I want two things at the same time:

- have the script output to stdout (which is directed to a log file)
- detect whether the upload succeeded

As far as I know, curl returns an exit code of `0` even in 401(unauthorized) or 407(conflict) situations. The `--fail` option can be used to change this behavior, but it suppresses stdout.

What would be the best workaround for this? `tee` and `grep`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl` writes its output to `stderr(2)`, the error stream instead of `stdout(1)`. Redirect it on the command using `2>&1`

```
curl --fail --anyauth --user user:password file http://webdav-server/destination/ 2>&1 > logFile
retval=$?
if [ $retval -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "curl command succeeded and the log present in logFile"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're finding this question in the future, you can now use [the new fail-with-body flag](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2021/02/11/curl-fail-with-body/).